# MySQL query to show all the hours within the next month

Tags: mysql, database, function, date

How would I put together a query to display all of the hours in the next week as I want to compare a timetable against this for appointment purposes.

Thanks for any help!

edit--

the expected result would be great as between 9 to 5

| client_date        |    client_time    |
10/01/2010       09:00:00
10/01/2010       10:00:00
10/01/2010       11:00:00
10/01/2010       12:00:00
10/01/2010       13:00:00
10/01/2010       14:00:00
10/01/2010       15:00:00
10/01/2010       16:00:00
10/01/2010       17:00:00

Comment: The question isn't clear. Please add example of output you want to be produced.

Comment: updated sorry, thanks for reply

Comment: What do you mean by "compare a timetable against this?"  SQL supports date/time operations in queries, so hopefully you're not replicating that.

Comment: I have a table containing dates and times of clients that a university office has to see. I want to show dates and times in the next week that are not already taken. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: SQL isn't good for generating data. That's what programming languages are for.

Comment: Now it's better. But still not enough data. Please give more details. E.g. "I have tables X, Y, Z with the following structure: ... I want to run a query to produce the following output: ..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a temporary table in a stored procedure.

```
DELIMITER ;;
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS ListHours ;;
CREATE PROCEDURE ListHours()
BEGIN
DECLARE curDT DATETIME;
DECLARE today DATETIME ;
DECLARE nextSaturday DATETIME;
DECLARE nextSunday DATETIME;
DECLARE iterDate DATETIME;
DECLARE iterDateTime DATETIME;
DECLARE iterBound DATETIME;
DECLARE resDate DATETIME;
DECLARE resTime DATETIME;
DECLARE delta INT;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tempNextWeek;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tempNextWeek
(
    client_date VARCHAR(20),
    client_time VARCHAR(20)
);
DELETE FROM tempNextWeek;
SET curDT = NOW();
SET today = ADDTIME(SUBTIME(curDT , TIME(curDT)) , '9:0:0');
SET delta = 8 - DAYOFWEEK(today);  
SET  nextSunday = ADDDATE(today , INTERVAL delta DAY);
SET  nextSaturday = ADDTIME(nextSunday , '6 0:0:0');
-- select today , delta , nextSaturday , nextSunday ;
SET iterDate = nextSunday;
WHILE iterDate <= nextSaturday DO
    SET iterDateTime = iterDate;
    SET iterBound = ADDTIME(iterDateTime, '8:0:0');
    WHILE iterDateTIme <= iterBound DO
        INSERT tempNextWeek (client_date, client_time) VALUE ( DATE_FORMAT(iterDateTime, '%Y-%m-%d'), DATE_FORMAT(iterDateTime, '%H:%i:%s') );
        SET iterDateTime = ADDTIME(iterDateTime , '1:0:0');
    END WHILE;
    SET iterDate = ADDTIME(iterDate , '1 0:0:0');
END WHILE ;
SELECT * FROM tempNextWeek;
-- drop table if exists tempNextWeek;
END;;
DELIMITER ;

CALL ListHours();
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a table to store the date and time values.

```
CREATE TABLE calendarhours (caldaytime DATETIME);
```

You will then need to create a stored procedure to loop through the two dates and insert the date time values for the time sheet times into the table.

```
DELIMITER $$    

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `timesheetdays`(startdate DATETIME, enddate DATETIME)    
BEGIN    
    DECLARE tempdate DATETIME;    


    DELETE FROM `calendarhours`;    

    -- set the temp date to 9am of the start date     
    SET tempdate = DATE_ADD(DATE(startdate), INTERVAL '0 9' DAY_HOUR);     

    -- while the temp date is less than or equal to the end date, insert the date    
    -- into the temp table    
    WHILE ( tempdate <= enddate ) DO    
        BEGIN    
            -- insert temp date into temp table    
            INSERT INTO `calendarhours` (caldaytime) VALUES (tempdate);    
            -- increment temp date by an hour    
            SET tempdate = DATE_ADD(tempdate, INTERVAL '0 1' DAY_HOUR);    

            -- if the temp date is greater than 5 PM (17:00) then increment to the next day    
            IF TIMEDIFF(tempdate, DATE_ADD(DATE(tempdate), INTERVAL '0 17' DAY_HOUR)) > 0 THEN    
                BEGIN    
                    -- increment to the next day    
                    SET tempdate = DATE_ADD(DATE(tempdate), INTERVAL '1 9' DAY_HOUR);     
                    -- for business purposes, if the day is a Saturday or a Sunday increment     
                    -- until we reach Monday    
                    WHILE ( DAYNAME(tempdate) = 'Saturday' OR DAYNAME(tempdate) = 'Sunday' ) DO    
                        BEGIN    
                            SET tempdate = DATE_ADD(DATE(tempdate), INTERVAL '1 9' DAY_HOUR);     
                        END;    
                    END WHILE;    
                END;    
            END IF;    
        END;    
    END WHILE;    

    -- return all the inserted date and times    
    SELECT * FROM calendarhours ORDER BY caldaytime;    

END
```

This procedure will then loop through the two dates, starting from 9 am each day and finishing at 5pm each day (17:00). When the time reaches 18:00, the procedure increments to the next day and starts again at 9 am.

If you are doing a standard business week timesheet, then if the day is equal to Saturday or Sunday, it will increment until it reaches Monday.

To test this I used the following statements:

```
CALL `timesheetdays`(NOW(), DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL '5 0' DAY_HOUR));    
SELECT * FROM `calendarhours`;
```

This tests the procedure from today to 5 days from today and shows the hours as required. The first statement adds the records to the table and then returns the records, the second statement returns the records from the table.